# Convert UTC string to time object

Tags: datetime, go, time

I have this datetime, or something that looks like it.

```
2014-11-17 23:02:03 +0000 UTC
```

I want to convert this to a time object and I've been unable to produce any output from `time.Parse` apart from:

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

I've tried these layouts:

```
time.RFC3339
0001-01-01 00:00:00 0000 UTC
2016-10-10
time.UnixDate
```

And a few more - none have worked.

This is how I'm calling `parse` :

```
updatedAt, err := time.Parse(time.UnixDate, updatedAtVar)
```

How do I create a time object from a string?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most likely you used a wrong layout, and you didn't check the returned error.

The layout must be this date/time, in the format your input time is:

```
Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
```

See this working code:

```
layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, "2014-11-17 23:02:03 +0000 UTC")
fmt.Println(t, err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hW-XeuJpXn)):

```
2014-11-17 23:02:03 +0000 UTC <nil>
```

**EDIT:**

In your question you included a `+` sign in your input time (as part of the zone offset), but you have error with times of other formats.

[`Time.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String) uses the following format string:

```
"2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST"
```

So either use this to parse the times, or use [`Time.Format()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) to produce your string representations where you can specify the layout, so you can use the same layout to parse the time strings.

**2nd round:**

You're including your time strings in URLs. The `+` sign is a special character in URL encoding: it denotes the space. So the `+` gets converted to space (and so it vanishes from your time string). Use proper URL encoding! Check out the [`net/url`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) package, and [this example](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#example_Values).

Comment: lol..yes. I used the wrong layout. I have no idea what layout to use. I just tried `"2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST"` and it didn't work either.

Was wondering if someone knew what layout to use because this is a common format.

I'm literally going `time.Now()`, converting it to String, and passing it in to unpack (writing an integration test)

Comment: @praks5432 What do you mean? It's not working for you? Click on the Playground link in my answer and try it yourself.

Comment: I pasted in `2014-11-17 23:02:03 0000 UTC` which is the output of `time.Now().String()` (I froze time - for a test)

I get this error in your playground `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC parsing time "2014-11-17 23:02:03  0000 UTC" as "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST": cannot parse "UTC" as "-0700"`

Comment: @praks5432 You have a missing `+` sign in your input, as part of the zone offset.

Comment: Yes. I know. I don't control that. I'm passing in `time.Now().String()`. That's from Go. How can we have a function in one package that won't take the output of another function in the same package that seem to be designed to work together?

Comment: I'd rather not take the time from my url, break it apart, add the plus and then convert to time. There *should* be an easy way to do this.

Comment: So I pass this time in as an URL parameter. When I unpack that using `r.URL.Query()["updated_at"]`, I get that output. I'm creating the time like this - `time.Now().String()`, and `2014-11-17 23:02:03 0000 UTC` is what is coming back to me as a URL param.

Comment: @praks5432 You didn't say anything about including times in URLs unencoded. `+` is a special symbol which means a space. See edit.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh is that just using `url.Encode` on my path?

Answer (score 8):

Didn't see this yet but for those that don't know the formats, time has the formats builtin as constants. so you can reference them when parsing or formating.

```
time.Parse(time.RFC3339, <your time.Time object here>)
<time.Time object>.Format(time.RFC3339) //or other type of formats
```

Here they are for reference

```
ANSIC       = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"
UnixDate    = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006"
RubyDate    = "Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006"
RFC822      = "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"
RFC822Z     = "02 Jan 06 15:04 -0700" // RFC822 with numeric zone
RFC850      = "Monday, 02-Jan-06 15:04:05 MST"
RFC1123     = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"
RFC1123Z    = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700" // RFC1123 with numeric zone
RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
Kitchen     = "3:04PM"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are likely using the wrong layout. As explained in [`time.Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse), you need to specify a layout that helps Go to understand how the date passed as input is formatted.

There are predefined layouts (like the ones you were using), but none matches your input. Hence you need to define a custom layout.

A layout uses the following date as reference:

```
Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006
```

The layout is nothing else that a representation of that date, that matches the representation of your input:

```
t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST", "2014-11-17 23:02:03 +0000 UTC")
```

Also remember to check `err` for errors. It's likely your attempts returned an error, but you didn't check it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 UTC", "2014-11-17 23:02:03 +0000 UTC")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand. But what I'm doing is using `time.Now().String` as an url parameter. I'm then unpacking that parameter and trying to convert back to a time (this is a test that I'm writing). 

The output I get from `time.Now().String` once it is unpacked is `2014-11-17 23:02:03  0000 UTC`, which is not being parsed. 

I know I have the wrong layout. I'm trying to find which layout.